# JQuery change image src on mouseover not working in IE7 and 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have a set of images which I want the source to change on mouseover. My code works fine in everything except IE 7 and 8 - when I hover over the image it just changes to a broken image link.

My code is:

```
$(".socialicon").each(function() {
   $(this).find("img")
        .mouseover(function() { 
            var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "hover.png";
            $(this).attr("src", src);
        })
        .mouseout(function() {
            var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("hover.png", ".png");
            $(this).attr("src", src);
        });
});
```

Would anyone know if there is something I have to change to have this work in IE 7 and 8?

Comment: can you add a `console.log(src)`/`alert(src)` in the mouseover handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should debug on IE7&8 - what is the value of `$(this).attr("src")` and what `src` attribute has the element after enter with the mouse over the element? I suppose, that the IE maybe returns an absolute path to the image, like "http://example.com/image.png" - in this case your RegEx would not work.

Why not calling

```
var src = $(this).attr("src").replace(".png", "hover.png");
```

instead of

```
var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "hover.png";
```

this would be more consistent regarding the `mouseout` method.